# Convert String to Variable Name

Tags: c#, c#-2.0

I need get combobox by string. Not worked.

```
 for (int i = 0; i < Slots.Count; i++)
        {
            var field = (ComboBox)this.GetType().GetField("cbSlots" + i).GetValue(this);
            field.DataSource = Slots[i.ToString()];
        }
```

Comment: You need to provide a little more detail than that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand the question, from your form, you could do

```
this.Controls.Find("name_of_your_combobox");
```

Comment: The syntax is `this.FindControl("name_of_your_combobox")`

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.controlcollection.find.aspx

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to access a `ComboBox` using its name as string, so you need to look for that in `this.Controls` like so:

```
ComboBox myCombo = (ComboBox)this.Controls["cbSlots" + i.ToString()];
```